# java 2d graphics array over an image

Tags: java, image, graphics, jpanel, multidimensional-array

I have built a JPanel which is painted based on a 2D array of data which the user can draw on.

I'm wondering if it is possible to somehow allow the user to upload a background picture, then set the size of the array based on the image to allow them to draw over it by filling in array cells. Then of course, rubbing out the colour in a cell should get back the original segement of the image.

Is this at all possible? I haven't found anything? I have the array at the moment and drawing using a MouseMotionListener but can't seem to find a way to set the 2D array size based on an image and then display it behind the 2d array.

Comment: Not my down-vote by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway, got some research to do I guess!

Comment: Yep, but it will be worth it in the end. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if it is possible to somehow allow the user to upload a background picture, then set the size of the array based on the image to allow them to draw over it by filling in array cells. Then of course, rubbing out the colour in a cell should get back the original segement of the image.

Yes this is definitely possible. The key as in all programming is to break down a big problem into little steps and then try to solve each small step, one at a time.

> Is this at all possible? I haven't found anything?

Your question is much too broad to find a complete or even partial solution by searching online. Again you can find solutions for each individual step, but you first have to create your steps. Once this is accomplished then it will be easy to find tutorials and solutions for each step that you may be stuck on.

> I have the array at the moment and drawing using a MouseMotionListener but can't seem to find a way to set the 2D array size based on an image and then display it behind the 2d array.

Show us what you have and where you're stuck.  We'll need code. And please note, the more specific your question, usually the better and more specific will be our answers. Your current question is in a nut-shell "is this possible", and the answer is of course "yes", but short of that, I'm not sure what else to say without knowing more about where in particular you may be stuck.